# Android TextView carry text by letters

Tags: android

Is there any way to carry text in TextView by letters in Android?

If no settings have been set – TextView carries text by words and situation is possible when with too long word you have big whitespace in TextView.

Example – what I’m talking about:
[image: Carry text by words]

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it at the TextView in XML, I would try giving it the attribute:

```
android:singleLine
```

If you have to do it in Java, there are a couple of options to keep it on the same line:

```
textView.setSingleLine();
textView.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
```

If you do want multiple lines, but you want it to break in a way that doesn't split it on the word, you might have to do it manually by analyzing the width of the TextView and how many characters can fit on a line, then inserting newlines appropriately. The two above methods will keep the contents of the TextView on one line, and it'll scroll horizontally. You can look into how [this person](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/RnVJoxgbxrM/kJN3k6V-7DIJ) is doing it.

Another option is to look into the android:ellipsize attribute, but I don't think it'll do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, the closest solution is to analyze manually the content going to be placed on TextView to split it. But I'll continue to look for simpler way.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. From looking around, it seems like TextViews are pretty adamant about how they wrap text. It might be overkill, but you could make your own TextView that overrides how the default wraps text.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you want, but I would guess.... if you would like to display the TextView in a single line, without "breaking" the sentence, you should add `android:singleLine="true"` to the TextView.

Otherwise, you may replace the "_" characters with space, in this case I believe it will carry the text, from the last space.

Comment: Yes, the solution "replace the "_" characters with space, in this case I believe it will carry the text" is possible in general,but in this case it's impossible - text are just filenames, I can't modify it.

Comment: Well, when clicking the TextView, you may remake the text back, by replacing this time spaces with "_" character, and use it as a file name. Of course, this implies some more work.

Comment: @AndyRes You would never want to modify how the filename is displayed to the user; that would lead to mass confusion, panic, and eventually the annihilation of all civilization. Or the user will be angry and uninstall your app. One of those.